# Change the background of the Row containing the column headings in Table component of ANTD

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the ANTD Table Component and I just need to change the background of the Row that contains the headings of the columns.

```
<Table
  dataSource={tableData}
  columns={columns}
  pagination={false}
  tableLayout="auto"
/>
```

I want to change the background color of the columns of the Table.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the using this class on your css file:

```css
th.ant-table-cell {
  background-color: aqua !important;
}
```

it's not a good practice use important, but i think don't have another way